# Subframes of two adjacent images with titles

Tags: beamer

I am using the beamer style and would like to have two graphs side by side and also have subframe titles (Gender and Age group) as shown below

[image]

The syntax am currently using is

```
\section*{Section 1}
% 
\begin{frame}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{output/gender.png}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{output/age.png}
\end{frame}
```

The separate images can be found below

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\column{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\textbf{Figure 1}
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\textbf{Figure 2}
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks so much for your help. Could you kindly share ideas on how to make the text to appear a little bit on top of the page as compared to the current one?